# Alternative to Apache Sqoop -- Bulk Transfer from RDBMS to HDFS

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to migrate data from Postgres to HDFS (ideally stored in parquet). Apache Sqoop was built for this purpose, but it was moved into Attic. There are a large number of different tables I'm migrating, and some table are huge (billions of rows).

I tried several approach:

1. Use Postgres COPY to csv and put to HDFS: 
   The issue is the copy is very slow for large table
2. Use Spark: 
   I tried to build a general spark job to do JDBC read, and write to Parquet on HDFS. This approach conceptually works. But many of my tables don't have an evenly distributed numeric column, thus it's hard to do the partitions of read and cause many jobs fail.

I'm wondering if there are any good products or open-source projects that's a great fit in this case.

Comment: How large are the tables? Does it have to be hdfs? I feel like Clickhouse or CockroachDB would offer you better query options than translating data to a columnar data format

Comment: `copy is very slow`, how fast is your storage? How many GB/s can it handle? And how large, in GB/TB/PB, are your tables?

Comment: for your question 2, you can use timestamp to evenly distribute instead of numeric column.. `spark jdbc` quit faster if you tune it correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens
The reason COPY is slow, to my understanding, is that it issues only one SELECT statement to Postgres, there is no parallelism help with performance